# args must be a dictionary error while using ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I am working on Ansible playbook to execute some of my tasks. In one of my tasks, I need to switch to particular directory and then execute a command using sudo but I need to do all these things by switching to root user first otherwise it won't work. So in general this is what I do without ansible:

```
david@machineA:/tmp/parallel-20140422$ sudo su
root@machineA:/tmp/parallel-20140422# sudo ./configure && make && make install
```

After above steps, I see GNU parallel library is installed in my system correctly. But with the below steps using Ansible, I am getting an error:

```
- name: install gnu parallel 
  shell: ./configure && make && make install
  args:
    chdir=/tmp/parallel-20140422
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: root
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
fatal: [machineA] => args must be a dictionary, received chdir=/tmp/parallel-20140422
```

I am working with 1.5.4 ansible. I am not sure what's wrong here with my ansible tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task should probably look like this:

```
- name: install gnu parallel 
  shell: ./configure && make && make install
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/parallel-20140422
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: root
```

I'm a bit confused that you have to give `root` as `sudo_user`, because that's the default as far as I know. But then again, if it works for you, it works.